# UIDatePicker with 2 Textfields (from/until date) can't set the right date at "until"textfield

Tags: ios5, datepicker, uidatepicker, xcode4.3

i have one datepicker. i wanna let the user choose the date and time in "Von"textfield ( which starts at tomorrow at 9 am ) and then a until textfield "bis" ( which starts 1.5 hours later).

everything works fine. but when i click on the "von" textfield. my datepicker dint set himself the correct time.

Here are some screenshots: 
[from textfield](http://i44.tinypic.com/1omus3.jpg), [until textfield](http://i42.tinypic.com/i1y876.jpg)

ViewDidLoad:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    [gregorian setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

    NSDateComponents *nowComponents = [gregorian components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit| NSWeekdayCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:today];


    [nowComponents setWeek: [nowComponents week]]; 
    [nowComponents setDay:[nowComponents day]+1];
    [nowComponents setHour:9]; 
    [nowComponents setMinute:0];
    [nowComponents setSecond:0];

    today = [gregorian dateFromComponents:nowComponents];

    NSDate *tomorrowat9am = [gregorian dateFromComponents:nowComponents];
    //DatePicker wird erstellt

    self.thePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 152, 325, 300)];
    self.thePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;
    [thePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateChanged) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];



    //starts from tomorrow at 9 am
    NSDate *pickereinstelldate= tomorrowat9am;

    [self.thePicker setDate:pickereinstelldate];

    //set the right format
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy  HH:mm"];
    NSString *datum =[dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.thePicker.date];


 //set the date at textfield "bis" to 1.5 hours later

    NSDate *neuesdatum = [beginningOfWeek dateByAddingTimeInterval:3600*1.5];         NSString *neuesd = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:neuesdatum];


    //set the textfield with the new date
    tfVon.text=datum;
    tfBis.text=neuesd;

    [self.view addSubview:thePicker];
    self.thePicker.hidden=YES;
    tfVon.inputView=thePicker;
     tfBis.inputView=thePicker;
}
```

here is the action:

```
-(IBAction)dateChanged
{
    self.date = [thePicker date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy  HH:mm"];
    NSString *datum =[dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.date];
    NSDate *neuesdatum = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:3600*1.5];
    NSString *neuesd = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:neuesdatum];

   //when i click on "Von" textfield
    if (dateBOOL==YES)

    {
        tfVon.text=datum;

        tfBis.text=neuesd;

    }
    //when i click on "bis" textfield
    if (dateBOOL==NO) {
        tfBis.text=neuesd;

        }    

}
```

here is where i set my datebool to no:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{


    if (textField==tfVon)
    {

        dateBOOL=YES;
        self.thePicker.hidden=NO;

        return YES;
    }
    if (textField==tfBis)
    {

        dateBOOL=NO;
        self.thePicker.hidden=NO;
        return YES;
    }

    }
return YES;

}
```

Comment: unclear question. please make it clear

Comment: When do you show the date picker? And where do you set `dateBOOL` to `NO`? Can you post some code?

Comment: i show my datepicker when the textxfield is selected (i updated my code). The datebook is in textfieldshouldbeginediting

Answer (score 0):

The last method you posted never makes it to the last Return YES. You have an extra }.

"my datepicker dint set himself the correct time."
Your question isn't totally clear but from what I gather you are trying to set the date picker to the correct time after selecting the "bis" textfield.

[datePicker setDate:neuesdatum animated:NO];

If you are trying to set the bis textfield to the new date you must use the dateformatter again and set the textfield to that new date.

What value is the following line (neuesd) giving you currently? 
NSString *neuesd = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:neuesdatum];

Comment: i deleted some code that isnt important and i forgot to delete the } sign. nsstring *neuesd takes the value from the datepicker and set it to 1.5 hours later. When i click on the "bis" textfield i want to set the datepicker date to neuesd. so i can start at 1.5 hours later